# dplyr filter() returns <0 rows> for some, but not all column values

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am using `filter()` to subset a `data.frame` based on values of a column *Kappa* but `filter()` returns `<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)` for certain values of *Kappa*. When trying to reproduce my problem defining the same subset of my df, the problem is gone.  So I´ll try to explain the issue, using the real (not reproducable) df and then the reproduced data. First, here´s the issue using a subset of my real df:

```
Res <- Res_w_long[1:5,1:4]  # subset of my real data

> Res
    T Kappa Y alpha
1 283  0.70 1   0.4
2 283  0.75 1   0.4
3 283  0.80 1   0.4
4 283  0.85 1   0.4
5 283  0.90 1   0.4

> str(Res)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ T    : num  283 283 283 283 283
 $ Kappa: num  0.7 0.75 0.8 0.85 0.9
 $ Y    : num  1 1 1 1 1
 $ alpha: num  0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4

> Res %>%
+   filter(Kappa == 0.8) 
[1] T     Kappa Y     alpha
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

> Res %>%
+   filter(Kappa == 0.85) 
    T Kappa Y alpha
1 283  0.85 1   0.4
```

And heres my unsuccesful attempt to reproduce the issue building the df from scratch instead of subsetting my data:

```
> Res2 <- data.frame(T = c(283.0, 283.00, 283.0, 283.00, 283.0),
+                   Kappa = c(0.7, 0.75, 0.80, 0.85, 0.9),
+                   Y = c(1.0, 1.00, 1.0, 1.00, 1.0),
+                   alpha = c(0.4, 0.40, 0.4, 0.40, 0.4))

> str(Res2)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ T    : num  283 283 283 283 283
 $ Kappa: num  0.7 0.75 0.8 0.85 0.9
 $ Y    : num  1 1 1 1 1
 $ alpha: num  0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.4

> Res2 %>%
+   filter(Kappa == 0.8) 
    T Kappa Y alpha
1 283   0.8 1   0.4
   
> Res2 %>%
+   filter(Kappa == 0.85) 
    T Kappa Y alpha
1 283  0.85 1   0.4
```

Any idea of why certain values of *Kappa* in the df *Res* cant be filtered out?? If not, maybe an idea of how I can reproduce this in a better way for you?

```
$version.string
[1] "R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)"

> packageVersion("tidyverse")
[1] ‘1.3.0’
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.2’
```

Comment: Can you try `filter(all.equal(Kappa, 0.8))`. For programming languages 0.8 is not always 0.8. There's a good post here on SO somewhere, just need to find it.

Comment: This might be a floating-point precision issue and has been asked many times. A workaround is to use `near`.

Comment: floating point issue.  check that in r `sqrt(2)^2 == 2` yields `FALSE`; but `sqrt(2)^2` yields `2`

Comment: I didnt expect that so this was a good reminder, thanks! ```Res_w_long %>% filter(near(Kappa,0.8)) ``` worked well.